# Display selected categories in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, catalogsearch

I have some code which displays all the catagories in my Magento store. What I want to do is add some similar code which will only display selected catagories (It is a group of subcatagories within Magento).

```
{{block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.category" template="catalog/category/home-list.phtml"}}
```

The home-list.phtml file contains the following code (Only pasting the start of it as I think thats the only bit that is relevant:

```
> $rootId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId(); $categories =
> Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
>     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
>     ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $rootId)
>     ->setOrder('position') // ->addAttributeToFilter('include_in_menu', 1) //this is needed if you want only the categories in the menu*/ -->
>     ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on weather you want to display the categories as a tree structure or not.

To get a tree structured response you can use the following code:

```
$category       = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
$parentId       = 2; // Replace with what category you want to use
$recursion      = 5;
$sorted         = true;
$asCollection   = false;
$loaded         = true;
$categories = $category->getCategories($parentId, $recursion, $sorted, $asCollection, $loaded);

foreach($categories as $child) 
{
    // Recursive rendering logic
}
```

Your own code example can be used, but you properly wont need to select all attributes for your loop.

```
$parentId   = 2; // Replace with what category you want to use 
$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', $rootId)
    ->setOrder('position') 
    ->addAttributeToFilter('is_active', 1);

foreach($categories as $category)
{
    // Render category logic
}
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your reply... I have tried the above code and unable to get it to work... I assume I have to replace the code above with the code you given?

Comment: Yes, and replace the $parentId variable with the ID of the parent category you want to display the children off.